# Why is applying a Python decorator with and without parenthesis different?

Tags: python-3.x, custom-data-attribute, python-decorators, default-parameters

I have a self-written class-based Python decorator. As far as I can see there is a difference, when I apply the decorator to a method in a class. Usually, decorators like `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod`, `@property` or `@unique` are applied without parenthesis. These decorators expect no parameters and are (mostly?) written as function-based decorators.

So in contrast to these examples, my decorator is class-based and expects an optional parameter while applying.

**My decorator:**

```
class DocumentMemberAttribute(Attribute):
  def __init__(self, value=True):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = value
```

**The Attributes class (the real decorator):**

```
class Attribute:
  __AttributesMemberName__ = "__pyattr__"

  def __call__(self, func):
    self._AppendAttribute(func, self)
    return func

  @staticmethod
  def _AppendAttribute(func, attribute):
    # inherit attributes and append myself or create a new attributes list
    if (Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__ in func.__dict__):
      func.__dict__[Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__].append(attribute)
    else:
      func.__setattr__(Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__, [attribute])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.__name__
```

**Example class:**

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, message=""):
    super().__init__()
    self.message = message

  @DocumentMemberAttribute
  def Method1(self):
    return "foo"

  @DocumentMemberAttribute()
  def Method2(self):
    return "bar"

  @DocumentMemberAttribute(False)
  def Method3(self):
    return "spam"

  @DocumentMemberAttribute(True)
  def Method4(self):
    return "egg"
```

The attached information is used in a custom `autodoc-skip-member` handler to decide if a method shall be documented or skipped. This is similar to the `docit` extension.

So when we look at the generated documentation (Sphinx), we can see these results:

> class **MyClass**(message="")
>
> > **Method1** = <lib.SphinxExtensions.DocumentMemberAttribute object at 0x0000000004AD9E80>
> >
> > **Method2()**
> >
> > **Method4()**

**What can we see here:**

- Method1 has no parenthesis indicating a function/method, hence it's regarded a class field and Sphinx uses `__str__` (or `__repr__`?) to document the initial value
- Method3 is not documented as intended.

**So my questions:**

- Why is there a difference in the behavior?
- MUST I apply class-based attributes with parenthesis?
- How should a user know how to use these 2 kinds of decorators?
  (I can document it for myself, but others might remember just the name und forget to add the parenthesis, because other decorators don't require them.)

---

[pyAttributes](https://github.com/Paebbels/pyAttribute?ts=2) is a set of attributes (real attributes, no Python attributes) written by me. They behave almost like [custom-attributes](/questions/tagged/custom-attributes) in .NET

Comment: as with most decoration definitions, the `@test` is equivalent to `@Test()` meaning, no parameters.  For example, I use decorators in the language *Dart* because it needs to leverage them to interact with front end markup.  I had to do a lot of research into annotations and their purposes and how/what they are used for

Comment: Decorators evaluate an expression (the one following the `@`) and call the result of that expression, passing the decorated item as an argument and replacing it with the returned value. `func` is different from `func()`, so `@func` is different from `@func()`.

Comment: http://click.pocoo.org/5/ for a way of doing what was described in your README without trying to fit .NET idioms into Python, by the way.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, `@deco \n class foo:` gets translated to `class foo: \n foo = deco(foo)`. I noticed that PyCharm colors function-based decorators in blue and class-based decorators in red. Other then this, how should a user know how to call/apply a decorator?

Comment: @Ryan Or do you mean this translation: `@deco() \n class foo:` gets translated to `class foo: \n foo = deco()(foo)` ??

Comment: Yes. `@expr class foo:` is `foo = (expr)(foo)` for any `expr`, so `deco()(foo)` is correct.

Comment: Can you write up this comment as an answer.

Comment: @Ryan pyAttributes implements attributes in general. The package is shipped with a set of attributes for argparse, which allow a nicer interface to apply argparse parameters directly to the handler method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ryan pointed out, the string behind the `@` sign is an expression, which gets translated to a function call. The parameter of that call is the object, to which the decorator was applied.

**Example 1 - function-based decorators:**

I'll use the `enum.unique` decorator. It is written as a function.

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
  foo = 0
  bar = 1
```

Gets translated to

```
from enum import Enum, unique

class MyEnum(Enum):
  foo = 0
  bar = 1

MyEnum = unique(MyEnum)
```

**Example 2 - class-based decorators:**

I'll use the decorator from the question. It is written as a class.

```
class MyClass:
  @DocumentMemberAttribute()
  def Method1():
    pass

  @DocumentMemberAttribute(True)
  def Method2():
    pass
```

Gets translated to

```
class MyClass:
  def Method1():
    pass

  Method1 = DocumentMemberAttribute()(Method1)

  def Method2():
    pass

  Method2 = DocumentMemberAttribute(True)(Method2)
```

Please note the empty parenthesis before passing `Method1` as an argument to the class' `__call__` method. These are the initializer's (`__init__`) parenthesis. So these parenthesis get filled for `Method2` when passing True as an argument.

**So in conclusion:**

- function-based decorators are applied without parenthesis
- class-based decorators are applied with parenthesis

---

**Note for PyCharm users:**

Look at the colored `@` sign:

- blue -> function-based decorator
- red -> class-based decorator